# Phpfox display html from php variable

Tags: php, html, smarty, phpfox

I am trying to display some html code from a php variable created in a controller like

```
$this->template()->assign(array('html' => "<p>Ajith chandran</p>"));
```

But when I write {$html} in template file,this html code is rendering as normal text and displaying it with full code in browser.And I tried this in two other ways like

```
{php}echo $html;{/php} and <?php echo $html; ?>
```

but both are not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should display this variable in Smarty using simply:

```
{html}
```

If for any reason I need to use `{php}` tag what I really don't recommend (it's a bad practice and in Smarty 3.1 is deprecated) you can display `html` value using:

```
{php} echo $template->getTemplateVars('html'); {/php}
```

Of course those both syntaxes should be used in TPL file and not in PHP file. If you want to use in PHP file any Smarty variable you could probably use in your case:

```
echo $this->template()->getTemplateVars('html');
```

What you should also consider is **security of this solution**. You should think about escaping your output or at least strip some tags. Now you can set`<script>alert('I am a very bad script');</script>` to `html` variable and user will see JavaScript alert.  I assume you might not know what your `html` variable will store and Smarty by default doesn't escape variables what can make to serious problems with your site.

So you could either use for example:

```
{$html|escape:"html"}

{php} echo htmlspecialchars($template->getTemplateVars('html')); {/php}
```

to display those data safely or use global setting [escape_html](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl) to do it for all Smarty variables:

In PHP

$this->template->escape_html = true;

In Smarty:

```
{$html}

{php} echo htmlspecialchars($template->getTemplateVars('html')); {/php}
```

As you see when using `{php}` tag even if setting `escape_html` to true you need to escape data in PHP otherwise you will display data as they were set.

Answer (score 0):

Either set `$escape_html` to false in Smarty or use `{$html nofilter}`

See: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl